# meaning of action-response style web framework (Spring MVC 3)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, spring-3

I am learning Spring MVC. In the [SPRINGSOURCE BLOG](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/01/04/green-beans-getting-started-with-spring-mvc/) The author Colin Sampaleanu says that "Spring MVC, a part of the core Spring Framework, is a mature and capable action-response style web framework".

In effort to understand the meaning of action-response style web framework I did a little research but dint seem find the exact meaning of it. What does exactly does the **action-response style web framework** mean? Is there any specific technical significance for it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the distinction they are making is that it is not exclusively request-response (i.e. straight http webserver) in that a post, put, etc (other HTTP methods) may alter data in the system or influence the response from the application.